# Click other element same as click this element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry for the title may seem confusing.

i have 2 element. with no relation like parent or child.

```
<div class="alpha"></div>
<div class="beta"></div>
```

The `class=alpha` have event, if we click it's, there is will be a fade in or fade out element (which is done by jQuery).

now i want to make simulation like. if we click `class="beta"` it will be the same as we click `class="beta"`.

---

more details is like if we click `beta` the `alpha` will show it's fadein fadeout effect :)

how we can make it?

many thanks

Comment: I found [this](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-copy-the-click-event-from-one-element-to-another), could be useful...

Comment: Somebody needs to fix the grammar on this one (no offense Gus but it's not very easy to understand). I don't have the rep points yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, you can call the `.click()` function directly or make use of `.trigger()` and pass it `"click"`. So either:

```
$(".beta").click();
```

Or

```
$(".beta").trigger("click");
```

Either one of these methods will call your click handler for `.beta`

If you meant to ask, if I click `.alpha`, I want to simulate a click on `.beta`, then this is what you want:

```
$("body").delegate(".alpha", "click", function() {
    $(".beta").click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> now i want to make simulation like. if we click class="beta" it will be the same as we click class="beta".

Not 100% sure what you mean with that. My guess is what you want is...

```
$('.alpha').click(function() { $('.beta').click(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean "if we click class="beta" it will be the same as we click class="**alpha**"

If that's the case

```
$('div.beta').click(function(){
    $('div.aplha').trigger('click');
});
```